# Is there a way to make the console or terminal output change by just changing a variale in the python script

Tags: python, console

Good day all. Maybe there is something I don't understand. How can I get the output of my console to change by just changing a variable in this case a, b or c. Without reloading the console. I either get it to output once and then I have a blinking prompt or it prints massive amount of lines.  Here is my test:

```
a = 1 
b = 1 
c = 1 
print(a, b, c)

def messenger():
    while a and b and c:
            print("True")
    else:
            print("False")
            time.sleep(5)
```

So if I change variables: a,b or c in the script, save the file, then just observe the console for a change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You expect the contents of your screen to change _without_ running the program again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a,b,c are variables they are stored in memory that is allocated to the script during run time.

you can't change those values without re-running the script, which will freeup the old memory, reallocate new memory, and run your code.

I suspect your need for implementing such a solution, changing vars like this; will be way more work than you'll be comfortable implementing (the solution to this can be intermediate project on its own)

you are better of reading values into these vars from a file or db.

```
with open('filefora.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = int(f.readline())
with open('fileforb.txt', 'r') as f:
    b = int(f.readline())
while True:
    if a and b:
        print(True)  
    else:
        print(False)
    with open('filefora.txt', 'r') as f:
        a = int(f.readline())
    with open('fileforb.txt', 'r') as f:
        b = int(f.readline())
```

Now every time you change the value in the file for the respective var, the code will use that new value without having to rerun the script.

Even better would be to just rerun the file.

Comment: So the best way would be just to write it to a file and then read the file back to the console. The reason is that I dont want to open a terminal every time a, b or c changes.

Comment: @JohanLombard if you will be modifying a,b,c in the code, then yes you have to write that update into the respective file.

you're reasoning still does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

@Anu makes a good point for updating the values of a, b and c.
This code here is for printing the results to console without printing newlines.

```
import time

#This function does something to the values of a, b and c
def foo(a, b, c):
    return a, b, c
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
while True:
    a, b, c = foo(a, b, c)
    if a and b and c:
        print("\rTrue", end='')
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("\rFalse", end='')
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are completely unaware of how the program works or how it displays it in a console.

If I use Python as an example, and you run a program of Python, a console would always appear unless it is a `.pyw` instead of `.py`.

You might already know that Python is an interpreter language, and it converts into binary line by line, as opposed to other high-level languages like C++ and Java which first compiles the code.

Now, if you run your Python program, the interpreter will convert the whole program into machine readable state, and that's when it looks for errors, and after that, a console would appear showing you the outputs.

But, if you open the source code (human-readable code) and make changes and save, it wouldn't affect the console. Why? It's because that code is still the source code and is never converted to machine readable code unless you run it (which will open another console showing you the output of the saved changes of the source code).

By the question you asked, I suggest to close the program, make changes and rerun it. The answer by @Anu is beneficial for getting the saved data in the file and using the saved values as variables, rather than for the purpose you asked, as it exposes the program to a security breach.

Comment: Thanks 8D and Anu. Now that makes a lot more sense to me.